# ggplot2 centering the ylab title

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can anyone help me with centering the ylab title? `hjust` didnot not work. XXX should be aligned with ZZZZ. You can see the code and output graph below.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncZJR.png)

```
df4 <- data.frame(min_seg_size=c(1750,2000,2500,3000,1750,2000,2500,3000),
                  ratio= c(1.075281,1.088825,1.130137,1.056911,
                           0.9862678,0.9903035,0.9702444,0.995585),
                  IQ=c( "M","M","M","M",
                        "F","F","F","F"))
df4$IQ <- factor(df4$IQ, levels=c("M","F"))






scaleY<-seq(0.8,1.3,0.02) ylimt<-c((0.8-0.05), (1.3+0.05))

p192<-ggplot(df4, aes(x=min_seg_size, y=ratio, group=IQ)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=IQ))+
  geom_point(aes(color=IQ)) + scale_color_manual(values=c("#0072B2","#CC0000")) +
  ylab(expression(bold(paste("XXX \n YYY ZZZZ KKK"))) ) + xlab(expression(bold(paste("Minimum Segment Size (kb)"))))+
  theme( axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10,  margin = margin(t = 0, r =0, b = 0, l = 4,   unit = "mm")), 
         axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10,  margin = margin(t = 0, r =0, b = 0, l = 0,   unit = "mm")), 
         panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",      colour = "grey"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c( 1500,1750,2000,2500,3000,3500))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c( scaleY))+
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(size=12)) + 
  theme( # remove the vertical grid lines
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank() ,
    # explicitly set the horizontal lines (or they will disappear too)
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size=.1, color="black" )  ) 
p192
```

Comment: Try adding space like `ylab(expression(bold(paste("        XXX\n YYY ZZZZ KKK"))) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `expression(bold(paste(...` and set the fontface via `face = "bold"` inside `theme()`:

... and perhaps add a space in front of "XXX" or drop the superfluous " " alltogether, i.e. `"XXX\nYYY ZZZZ KKK"` (;

```r
df4 <- data.frame(min_seg_size=c(1750,2000,2500,3000,1750,2000,2500,3000),
                  ratio= c(1.075281,1.088825,1.130137,1.056911,
                           0.9862678,0.9903035,0.9702444,0.995585),
                  IQ=c( "M","M","M","M",
                        "F","F","F","F"))
df4$IQ <- factor(df4$IQ, levels=c("M","F"))

library(ggplot2)
scaleY<-seq(0.8,1.3,0.02) 
ylimt<-c((0.8-0.05), (1.3+0.05))

p192<-ggplot(df4, aes(x=min_seg_size, y=ratio, group=IQ)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=IQ))+
  geom_point(aes(color=IQ)) + scale_color_manual(values=c("#0072B2","#CC0000")) +
  ylab("XXX \n YYY ZZZZ KKK") + xlab("Minimum Segment Size (kb)")+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10,  face = "bold", margin = margin(t = 0, r =0, b = 0, l = 4,   unit = "mm")), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10,  face = "bold", margin = margin(t = 0, r =0, b = 0, l = 0,   unit = "mm")), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",      colour = "grey"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c( 1500,1750,2000,2500,3000,3500))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c( scaleY)) +
  theme(
     legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(size=12)) + 
   theme( # remove the vertical grid lines
     panel.grid.major.x = element_blank() ,
     # explicitly set the horizontal lines (or they will disappear too)
     panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size=.1, color="black" )  ) 
p192
```

[image]